# Launch Screen File with different images

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview, storyboard, launch-screen

My design team has given me various launch screen images for all types of screen sizes found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

I want to support iPhone 6+ and iPad Pro so I know launch screen files should be used instead of image assets.

However, **how do I specify in my launch screen file the different images for each screen size?** I thought size-classes would be the way to go but I can't differentiate between iPad Air 2 and iPad Pro that way.

There's also no iPad Pro image asset either.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at device specific image assets (on the attributes inspector of an image in an asset bundle).

It may be impossible to match the design exactly because you can't run code at this point.  It may be easier to explain this to the designers and have them design to the constraint.

One simple idea is to have a centered image at the correct resolution and to use a view underneath to have a background (color or tiled image).

Comment: I tried this, but iPad Pro doesn't have locations for iPad Pro...the newer devices require a Launch Screen File